# Formdata not posted to server

Tags: javascript, html, post, asp-classic

I have a problem to post form-data to the server.

I first tested how to implement posting form-data combining javascript and asp and with success!!! :-)

So, very typicall - implementing this strategy to the real code failed!!! :-(

The codes differs in that in the latter i create the checkboxes dynamically and the url is a bit different - that is same ip but with some arguments.

I am almost certain that the posting fails because I can see this in wirechark - analyzing the packages. In the first case - I can see checked items as a string separated with commmas. In the latter - I can not see any stringitems of checkbox-data.

first code (that works)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <form action="jstest.asp" method="post" name="myform">
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a   car<br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<%
description = request.form("vehicle")
response.write("sort = " & description)

%>
```

code that does not work

```
<form action="?dep=enviro&page=room&func=attach_objekt" method="post">

  <script type="text/javascript">


    <%for i = 0 to UBound(objArray) - 1%>

        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        x.setAttribute("value", "car");
        x.setAttribute("name", "vehicle");

        var y = document.createElement("label");
        y.innerHTML = "<%=objArray(i)%>"; 
        y.id="label_<%=objArray(i)%>";
        document.body.appendChild(x);
        document.body.appendChild(y);


    <%next%>


</script>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
```

Comment: You need to append the elements to the form, not the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append your elements in form not in body.

Try below code by replacing

```
document.body.appendChild(x);
document.body.appendChild(y);
```

to

```
document.forms['yourFormName'].appendChild(x);
document.forms['yourFormName'].appendChild(y);
```